# How to pass a list of strings into a user-defined function?

Tags: r, list, function

I wrote a simple function that takes an excel file and does some data cleaning. However, I have to repeat this over all files contained in a folder. So far the function works with a single file but when I iterate through the list, I get errors as listed below and only some data frames output (there should be 333 tables outputted). The goal of the project is to take all excel files, clean the data, merge all DFs together and then push to a database.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)
library(MESS)
library(stringr)

udFunction <- function(loc) {

  test <- read_excel(loc) #read location
  test <- test[-c(1:7),] #removes first 7 rows
  names(test) <- test[1,] #makes the first row into column name
  test <- test[-1,] #removes first row since it's copied to column name

  #Rename all column names
  names(test)[1] = "Time"
  names(test)[2] = "Sample"
  names(test)[3] = "Rename"
  names(test)[4] = "Test"
  names(test)[5] = "Test2"
  names(test)[6] = "Test3"
  names(test)[7] = "Test4"
  names(test)[8] = "Test5"
  names(test)[9] = "Test6"
  names(test)[10] = "Test7"
  names(test)[11] = "Test8"
  names(test)[12] = "Test9"
  names(test)[13] = "Test10"
  names(test)[14] = "Test11"
  names(test)[15] = "Test12"
  names(test)[16] = "Test13"
  names(test)[17] = "Test14"
  names(test)[18] = "Test15"
  names(test)[19] = "Test16"

  #Copy Time column to NewColumn
  test %<>% 
    mutate(NewColumn = Time) %>%
    mutate(Date = str_extract(loc, "\\d{6}")) #loc is from the path name

  test$NewColumn <- str_replace(test$NewColumn, "\\d", NA_character_) %>%
    filldown() #replaces any string without digits with NA

  test %<>%
     filter(!str_detect(test$Time, "[A-Za-z]"))  #filters anything with characters

}

loc <- "C:/PATH.../.../2019"
files = list.files(path = loc, pattern = ".xls$", full.names = TRUE) #files is a list of 333 path names. 

for (i in files) {
  cast = paste("CC", i, sep = "_")
  try(assign(cast, udFunction(i)))
}
```

I'm expecting data frames for all the files to output, however, I keep getting the same `Error in attr(x, "names") <- as.character(value) : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]`.

I'm assuming it has something to do with renaming the column names. Again all this works when I try it one by one but when I try to create a function and then iterate over the list of path names I get the error above.

Comment: Are you certain every excel file is being read properly? My guess would be that you're getting that error because of an empty test data frame.

Comment: We don't have enough to know for certain, but I find it useful at times to have "assertions" in functions like this. While you can use packages for that, the simplest would be something like: `stopifnot(is.data.frame(loc), ncol(loc) == 26L)`. (BTW: (1) are you using `dplyr` or `magrittr`? (2) Your renaming with individual `names(test)[...]` can easily be compacted into a single `names(test) <- c("Time", "Sample", ...)` or, since you already appear to be using it, `dplyr::rename` or `dplyr::select(newname=oldname, ...)`.)

Comment: Caio, you are right. I think the error comes from some files having one less column when I read them in. I'm going to look deeper to see if there's a way to still read those files and mark them as NA if the column is not presented.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

```
udFunction <- function(loc) {

  # read your excel file, skip the column names as you don't need them, and skip the first 8 rows
  test <- read_excel(loc, col_names = F, skip = 8)

  # rename your columns
  colnames(test) <- c("Time", "Sample", "Rename", "Test", paste0("Test", c(2:16)))


  #Copy Time column to NewColumn
  test %<>% 
    mutate(NewColumn = Time) %>%
    mutate(Date = str_extract(loc, "\\d{6}")) #loc is from the path name

  test$NewColumn <- str_replace(test$NewColumn, "\\d", NA_character_) %>%
    filldown() #replaces any string without digits with NA

  test %<>%
     filter(!str_detect(test$Time, "[A-Za-z]"))  #filters anything with characters

  return(test)

}

# list your xls files
files <- list.files(path = "C:/PATH.../.../2019", pattern = ".xls", full.names = TRUE) 

# use lapply to iterate the function over your files. This returns a list of data frames
lapply(files, udFunction)
```

Comment: Thanks this is much cleaner than my code. I just checked column by column for every file and I think the error occurs because some excel files have one less column than others.